# Space in URL parameter

Tags: parameters, uri, space

How can I give a **space** (I marked the space with a underline in the url) as character in a URL paramter? Such like this:

127.0.0.1:9000/test?param1=AfterThisThereIsSpace**_**&param2=HereNot

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Either `\ ` or `%20`

Comment: Hi - %20 works - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to encode those blank spaces with escaped hexadecimal equivalents,  in your case,

```
 127.0.0.1:9000/test?param1=AfterThisThereIsSpace%20&param2=HereNot
```

Here blank space is equivalent to **“%20”**.